# How to apply the attached formula on an array (sequence) to find subarrays with specific characteristics?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a scheduled elements(sequence of aircrafts stored in an array of aircrafts, each aircraft land on specific time). Now I want to split out this sequence into groups of sequences based on the result of the implementation of equation (attached). Any element in the array affected by the equation must be held. 
Ex: {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9} 
after applying the equation will get: { 1,2,3},{4,5,6}

[image]

Comment: So what is your exact question? How to copy data between Arrays?

Comment: The  equation as in the image attached

Comment: My math lessons are so long over, but when I understand it correctly, you want to calculate the difference in the departure times of the aircrafts and put all in one array until the difference to the departure time of the preceding aircraft is less than the separation time. When the separation time was violated, you create another array and start putting airplaned in this array until separation time is vialoted again and so on. You do this until all airplanes are put into one array. Correct?

Comment: Slightly correct. But what exactly I want to do is to understand the programming steps to apply the equation on the sequence or array

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's assume you have an array with aircrafts

```
Aircraft[] aircrafts = ...
```

The Aircraft class might be more complex, but it has at least a departure time associated with it (btw: we are not talking about software design here, you would normally not store the static Aircraft data and the dynamic schedule data for the Aircraft within one object. But for the sake of easiness it should be ok).

```
class Aircraft {
  // departure time in milliseconds
  private long departureTime;

  public long getDepartureTime()
  {
    return departureTime;
  }
}
```

Your method to create these different arrays could then look like this where `aircrafts` is the array of Aircrafts to check and `minDistance` is the minimum time between two aircrafts in milliseconds:

```
Aircraft[][] splitIntoChunks(Aircraft[] aircrafts, long minDistance)
{
  if (aircrafts != null && aircrafts.size() > 0)
  {
    // this will be the result of the method
    List<Aircraft[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // this is a temporary list that holds all Aircrafts until the next violation of the minimum distance check occurs
    List<Aircraft> temp = new ArrayList();
    temp.add(aircrafts[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < aircrafts.length; ++i)
    {
      Aircraft previous = aircrafts[i - 1];
      Aircraft current  = aircrafts[i];

      if (current.getDepartureTime() - previous.getDepartureTime() < minDistance)
      {
        // violation of min distance - add all Aircrafts of temp as an Array to the result list and clear the temp list so we can reuse it
        result.add(temp.toArray(new Aircraft[temp.size()]));
        temp.clear();
      }

      temp.add(current);
    }

    if (!temp.isEmpty())
    {
      result.add(temp.toArray(new Aircraft[temp.size()]));
    }

    return result.toArray(new Aircraft[result.size()][]);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: I consider Lists of arrays bad form. Use either List<List<Foo>> or a 2D array.

Comment: Oh and your temp list is using the raw type.

Comment: @Michael You are right. I did chane the return type to a 2D array. Personally I would prefer Lists, but the original author wanted to have arrays.